# Is iOS 15 kernel cache encrypted?

Tags: ios, kernel

I recently started researching ios kernel security and I've been struggling to find out whether the kernel cache is encrypted for iOS 15. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apple stopped encrypting iOS kernelcache since iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, from iOS 10 onwards, the kernel is not encrypted.  That is since 2016.

> Apple’s developer preview for iOS 10 has been available for more than a week, but there’s one big change that people are only noticing now — the kernel code is not encrypted.
>
> The kernel is the core of the operating system — it controls software requests and helps process them to instruct the device’s hardware. The kernel has always been encrypted in previous iOS versions, but with iOS 10’s developer preview it wasn’t, sparking surprise from technology researchers and security experts, according to MIT’s Technology Review.

From [iOS 10 kernel is not encrypted, and here's Apple reasoning](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/ios-10-kernel-not-encrypted/)